# Unable to find an entry point in DLL 'opengl32.dll' in screensaver

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk, windows-screensaver

I have very odd problem with my C# OpenTK screensaver application. When I compile the program and run it before changing the extension, as EXE file, it works properly. But when I change the extension to SCR and run it, it crashes with a System.EntryPointNotFound exception (glCreateProgram function in this case). In the debugger I have checked that when I run:

as EXE file:
GL.GetString(StringName.Vendor) -> "Intel"
GL.GetString(StringName.Version) -> "2.1.0 - Build 8.15.10.2622"

as SCR file:
GL.GetString(StringName.Vendor) -> "Microsoft"
GL.GetString(StringName.Version) -> "1.1.0"

In my application I am using parameterless constructor of GameWindow class to create OpenGL context. For little experiment I changed extension to BAT and it run perfectly well. I have no idea why my OpenGL context depends on file extension, I'm guessing that screensavers are executed by system on some kind of overlay but truly I couldn't find solution for this issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a Dll Hell problem, you've got more than one version of opengl32.dll on your machine.  Windows finds another one when you renamed it to .scr, no doubt the one in c:\windows\system32

Comment: I checked that, on my computer I have two copies of the library opengl32.dll - first in C:\Windows\System32\ and the second one in C:\Windows\winsxs\... but both files are identical versions.

Comment: Right, that's the Microsoft version.  You haven't found the Intel version yet.  Clearly your EXE program can.  Enable unmanaged debugging and look at Debug + Windows + Modules to see where it is located.

Comment: @mi_k: You should always use the opengl32.dll found in system32. glCreateShader is a extension function. OpenTK should deal with extension loading properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after long searching i found out that Intel blocks hardware support for screensavers using OpenGL. I have changed extension to "sCr" to fool driver and now everything works fine.

Link:
[opengl.org forum](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=238470)